# UWP Request Entity too large (413)

Tags: веб-программирование, uwp, request

Загружаю видео на сервер, ловлю 413-ую ошибку.
Находил много решений, но только для WCF.

Запрос делаю на Flurl.Http:

```
                try
            {
                res = await upload_url.PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp
                    .AddFile("video_file", buffer.AsStream(), "story.mp4", null, (int)buffer.Length)
                    ).ReceiveString();
            }
```

Как на UWP увеличить максимальную длину запроса?